# Delete record after confirmation

Tags: javascript, jsp

i have a table of articles for each item when i click delete button a popup of confirmation appear the problem is how to pass the Id of article so that when the user click on confirmation button the record will be deleted 
here is the code of the table

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="article">
    <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
        <c:forEach items="${articles}" var="o">
            <tr>
                <td>${o.id}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="media">
                        <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                            <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" width="100" src="http://cfisinergia.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/cfi-sinergia/files/WORKSHOPS/Workshop1.jpg" alt="...">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h4 class="media-heading">${o.titre}</h4>
                            ${o.description}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>${o.date}
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" data-placement="top" rel="tooltip">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                        </button>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" data-placement="top" rel="tooltip">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

and the code of the popup

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Delete this
                        entry</h4>
            </div>
            <div>le numero de l'article</div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span> Are you sure you want to delete this Record?
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer ">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Yes
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> No
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Set the `id` of the record to be deleted to a hidden form field using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution for my question

table code:

```
        <div class="tab-pane" id="article">
                    <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
                        <c:forEach items="${articles}" var="o">
                            <tr>
                                <td>${o.id}</td>
                                <td><div class="media">
                                        <a class="pull-left" href="#"> <img
                                            class="media-object img-thumbnail" width="100"
                                            src="http://cfi-sinergia.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/cfi-sinergia/files/WORKSHOPS/Workshop1.jpg"
                                            alt="...">
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <h4 class="media-heading">${o.titre}</h4>
                                            ${o.description}
                                        </div>
                                    </div></td>
                                <td><div class="pull-right">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>${o.date}
                                    </div></td>

                                <td><p>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit"
                                            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" data-placement="top"
                                            rel="tooltip">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </p></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="open-deleteDialog btn btn-danger btn-xs"
                                        data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#delete-article" data-placement="top"
                                        data-id="ISBN564541" rel="tooltip">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </table>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#ajoutart" data-placement="top" rel="tooltip">
                        <span>Ajouter Article</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

code of modal class :

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="delete-article" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-hidden="true"></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Delete this
                    entry</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>some content</p>
                <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span> Are you
                    sure you want to delete this Record?
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer ">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Yes
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> No
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".open-deleteDialog", function() {
    var ida = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body #id").val(ida);
    // As pointed out in comments, 
    // it is superfluous to have to manually call the modal.
    $('#delete').modal('show');
});
```

this link http://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/605/ was very useful